# Deploy de projeto em Laravel 5.4 no Umbler

Tags: laravel, deploy, laravel-5.4

Olá,

eu vi a comunidade brasileira de Laravel comentando sobre o Umbler um bom servidor BR para deploys de projetos em Laravel. Eu fui testar o deploy de um projeto, mas não consegui fazê-lo funcionar no serviço site PRO.
Primeiramente aqui estão os arquivos upados no umbler:

[image: Arquivos no Umbler]

Se fosse um shared host, teria funcionado normalmente, e meu servidor já está apontando pro meu domínio. Eu sei que existe um template  pra usar o laravel aqui no umbler, mas eu preciso usar o serviço Cloud Sites só pra poder usar o laravel?
Desde já agradeço!

Answer (score 1):

É só descer um nível de diretório para que o seu index.php possa ser localizado.
Vc deixou public/public/index.php

Answer (score 0):

Resolvido, foi um problema com o usuário FTP, no Umbler, não conseguia fazer o upload da pasta vendor corretamente, depois que eu troquei a senha do usuário FTP(não logava no filezilla), eu entrei pelo filezilla e implantei o site diretamente de lá!